# Django Channels testing fails

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm putting up django-channels on a basic django site, configured in the following way.

## consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

## routing.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from consumers import ChatConsumer

#supposed to be on the main routing
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/$', ChatConsumer),
]

#after linking to above as chat.routing
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

## settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'chatsys.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('35.185.80.98', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'channels',
]
```

After installing the necessary applications I went to the next step in the [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) that's testing this on the shell.

```
In [1]: import channels.layers

In [2]: from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

In [3]: async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-80e65666e9e2> in <module>()
----> 1 async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})

NameError: name 'channel_layer' is not defined

In [4]: channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

In [5]: async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-80e65666e9e2> in <module>()
----> 1 async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})

~/webapp/chatenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     62             )
     63         # Wait for results from the future.
---> 64         return call_result.result()
     65 
     66     def __get__(self, parent, objtype):

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    423                 raise CancelledError()
    424             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 425                 return self.__get_result()
    426 
    427             self._condition.wait(timeout)

...

    451 
    452     def _sock_connect(self, fut, sock, address):
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py in _sock_connect_cb(self, fut, sock, address)
    478             if err != 0:
    479                 # Jump to any except clause below.
--> 480                 raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
    481         except (BlockingIOError, InterruptedError):
    482             # socket is still registered, the callback will be retried later
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connect call failed ('35.185.80.98', 6379)
```

It fails to connect and returns a Connection failure.
I assumed possibly the issue was that redis was not active so I exited the shell and checked and this was the result.

```
(chatenv) muiruri_samuel@train:~/webapp/chatsys$ sudo docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8
87ee2decc507984ffa153f7b9367a51786bc16ebf6ea330ebb0a030d99b60854
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint infallible_payne (f40e48395d0e09e2741b1083b548ff2d0843f7ec150294
dbbb72acb3d5f61ea1): Bind for 0.0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated.
```

so the port is already allocated and it's running.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue was setting the IP of the server on settings instead of localhost

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

so replacing it to this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the server port. Is it available to connect from the outside from the server. I mean It's connect from the public internet. I think this is the issue is here.

Run this command in your Linux terminal or Windows cmd to check the port is available to connect from your physical machine network.

```
telnet 35.185.80.98 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```